# funcで返り値をdouble型にした時のreturnでのエラー

Tags: swift, xcode

funcで返り値をdouble型にした時、returnでエラーが出てしまいます。
原因がわかる方がいましたら、ご教授お願いします。

```
var pcascore:Array<Double> = [3.2, 2.4, 3.5, 1.3]

func arrayplus(pcascore : Double... )-> Double { // 引数の合計値を求める
    var total:Double = 0.0

    for n in pcascore {
        total += n
    }
    //print(total)
    pcaallscore.append(total)

    return pcaallscore
    // Cannot convert return expression of type '[Double]' to return type 'Double'
    // というエラーが出てしまいます。
}
```

Answer (score 1):

pcaallscore は Double のリストで、リターンするべきなのは Double（単体の変数）だからだと思います。
戻りを配列で返すのであれば関数の定義を、

```
func arrayplus(pcascore : Double... )-> Array<Double> {
```

とするべきではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

合計を返すだけなら `pcaallscore.append(total)` は不要で、
単に `return total` でよい、と思います。